# VB .NET and Databases

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Trying to get this bit of code to enter a player name fill it in the datarow then update it in the DB. It currentley updates in the datarow but I can not get the code right to update the DB. Could you please help cheers.

```
  Using da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Team1", con)
            da.Fill(ds, "BPAWA")

            txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("BPAWA").Rows(0).Item(1)

            T1P1 = InputBox("Name of Player 1")

            ds.Tables("BPAWA").Rows(0).Item(1) = T1P1

            ds.Tables("BPAWA").AcceptChanges()
            ds.AcceptChanges()

            da.Update(ds, "BPAWA")
            MsgBox("Player 1 Added Successfully")
        End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You OleDbDataAdapter is not linked to an actual command neither you seem to have created the adapter in your code. [See an example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Missing a line like this

```
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection);
```

so I could rewrite your code in this way (Avoiding the global variables)

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;"
    Dim dbSource As String = "Data Source = C:\BP_Table_Project.accdb"
    Dim ds as DataSet = new DataSet()

    Using con As OleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection()
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()

        MsgBox("Connection With Database Established", 0, "Database Connection")

        Using da as OleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Team1", con)
            Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Fill(ds, "BPAWA")
            ......

            da.Update(ds, "BPAWA")
            MsgBox("Player 1 Added Successfully")
        End Using
        MsgBox("Connection With Database Closed", 0, "Database Connection")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steve I tried yours and its throwing me a load of encapsulation errors?

Comment: Tested with a simple database and changed some declarations. Check the updated answer

Comment: Hey Steve, Thanks for all the help so far. It now runs with now errors running a check shows that the name has changed in the dataset. Though it dosent change the name in the DB. Do I need to run a SQL command or something? Regards

Comment: Readded the command builder to the code above. Please remove the AcceptChanges to your updated code. It is totally wrong to call AcceptChanges and then expect to save anything in the database. `AcceptChanges` change the property RowState of your rows to `Unchanged` so when you call Update there is nothing to save. [See the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx)

Comment: at da.Update(ds,"BPWA") its thorwing a Operation must use an updateable query. error. Does it need some sort of SQL update query?

Comment: Don't worry. The file was read-only. Thank you so much for all your help. I'll be sure to credit your help in the documentation :)

Answer (score -1):

Before `da.Update(ds, "BPAWA")`

Add:

```
ds.Tables("BPAWA").AcceptChanges()
ds.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: Wrong. If you call AcceptChanges, then the RowState property change to `Unchanged` and nothing will be saved to the database